# Loop for all outlook inspectors

Tags: vb.net, outlook

Lets say I have opened 3 outlook inspector.

How to loop for 3 outlook inspector?

So, I need a vb.net code like following;

```
For Each i In All.Outlook.Inspectors

Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code uses the Inspectors property and the Count property and Item method of the Inspectors object to display the captions of all inspector windows.

```
Dim myInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors  
Dim x as Integer  
Dim iCount As Integer 
Set myInspectors = Application.Inspectors  
iCount = Application.Inspectors.Count  
If iCount > 0 Then  
  For x = 1 To iCount
    MsgBox myInspectors.Item(x).Caption  
  Next x  
Else  
  MsgBox "No inspector windows are open."  
End If
```

You may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article helpful.

Comment: Solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I want to do the same in C# in VSTO add-in. There is no Item method in the Application.Inspector. Can you please help?